# Batch processing raster images with Arcpy

Tags: python, for-loop, batch-processing, raster, arcpy

I'm attempting to write a code in Python that will stack 5 band raster images that are all listed sequentially in a folder and then output the stacked images to a new folder. My first instinct was to automate some sort of for loop structure in arcpy with the composite band tool.

I'd like help with the following things:

1. I'm having issues getting started with the for loop. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

   ```
   import arcpy
   arcpy.env.workspace = ".\\"
   outws = "Stacked_Images_Folder"

   for rasters in folder:
       band1 = 
       band2 = 
       band3 = 
       band4 = 
       band5 =

       arcpy.CompositeBands_management("band1.tif;band2.tif;band3.tif;
       band4.tif, band5.tif","stacked_img.tif")
   ```
2. I'm trying to figure out how the script will know to move on to a new image after stacking 5 bands. Do I need to sort the images into separate folders before beginning, or is there a work-around, e.g. the code knows to move on to the next image after reaching 5 bands?

Comment: There isn't quite enough information in your question right now. What is the structure of `folder`? Is there a reason why you are including `arcpy.Composite....` in the for loop?

Comment: The folder structure sequentially lists bands of images: img1-b1, img1-b2, img1-b3,img1-b4, img1-b5, img2-b1...   I'm not sure where the composite band tool should be placed in the code, I just assumed it would be part of the loop, since the loop is designed to apply the tool to each set of 5 bands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a for loop to do this if your rasters are all in the same folder:

```
import arcpy
wd="Y:/" #have this as your directory where all rasters are located
arcpy.env.workspace = wd
raster_list=arcpy.ListRasters("", "tif")
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(raster_list,"stacked_img.tif") #will save output on the same folder specified above.
```

If you want to save it to a new subdir:

```
import os
outws = wd+"Stacked_Images_Folder/"
os.makedirs(outws)
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(raster_list, outws + "stacked_img.tif")
```

Now if you have multiple set of rasters to merge in the same folder that have a common starting file name, such as img1-b1, img1-b2, etc, you can make the entire process work with the following simple implementation:

```
import arcpy
image_names=["img" + str(s) for s in range(1,143)]
wd="Y:/" #have this as your directory where all rasters are located
arcpy.env.workspace = wd
for image_name in image_names:
    print image_name
    raster_list=arcpy.ListRasters(image_name+"-*", "tif")
    import os
    outws = wd+"Stacked_Images_Folder/"
    os.makedirs(outws)
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management(raster_list, outws + image_name+ "_stacked_img.tif")
```

Comment: One issue here - I'm not trying to create a single raster image from all of these bands. I'm trying to create 143 5-band raster images (there are 715 5-band images in my folder).

Comment: Sorry, but that was not clear from the original question. I have updated the code to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still getting and error on the last line. Error reads "Input Rasters: Value is required", as well as an error that the parameters are not valid.

Comment: check out what is in the raster_list vector, it may be that not all imgx have rasters, and thus the listraster command is producing an empty vector. To avoid this error, put the last line within an if loop that will only run if the length of raster_list>0. In either case, it is impossible to debug your secondary issues since there is no available info in your question. The code above is tested and works. Additional issues are likely beyond the scope of the question you asked.